How to stop adding offsets for the Date object when reading it from ASP.NET Core
I am developing a project with Angular and ASP.NET Core. I am sending this date from Angular to ASP.NET Core.
Date object from Angular:
2024-12-21T00:00:00

But when reading it in ASP.NET Core, it will look like this:
2024-12-20T18:30:00

How can I get rid of adding offsets for the date object when sending it from Angular frontend?
Thanks in advance.

If your project is .NET 7 or above and concerned only for the date, you can use DateOnly type. And In your front-end, you should pass the value without time to the controller: "2024-12-21".

Thank you for the reply. There are cases to send time as well. Like 2024-12-21T07:30:00. In that case I can not send the date only.

If you are receiving DAteTimeOffset, you may use date.LocalDateTime to get rid of offset.

Thank you for the comment. I want to capture exact date and time enters from the client form and take into the code in .net core.

It would be good to send the UTC offset / timezone with the value from your client app. That would remove any ambiguity from the back-end.

could you try to send the date in the UTC format:const utcDate = new Date(Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()));
in .net core use:DateTime utcDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(inputDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);

Please try the below code:
 const currentDate = new Date();
    const formattedDate = currentDate.toLocaleDateString('en-CA'); 
    console.log(formattedDate);

